# Finding the necessary $\delta$ for $\lim_{z \to 1+i}6z-4 = 2+6i$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Like the title says, I need to find the correct $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ in order to prove the aforementioned complex limit.  Now, I'm assuming $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{6}$, but I really am not too sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$|(2+6i)-(6z-4)| = |6(1+i)-6z| = 6 |(i+1)-z|$$

Thus whenever you have $|(i+1)-z| < \tfrac{\epsilon}{6}$ you also have $|(2+6i)-(6z-4)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Perfect. These, for some reason, seem harder when dealing with the 2 dimensional complex space.